# C# Reflection: GetMethods(..) failing to retrieve anything

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

I am currently trying to get a very specific set of methods but am failing to do so.
I need to get all methods that match a certain signature from all classes that implement a certain interface.

What I've got so far is:

```
IEnumerable<System.Type> classes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IActionMethod)).GetTypes().Where(x => x.GetInterface("IActionMethod") != null);
MethodInfo[] methods;
List<MethodInfo> relevant;
ParameterInfo[] parameters;
foreach(System.Type cls in classes)
{
    methods = cls.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    relevant.Clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < methods.Length; i++)
    {
        parameters = methods[i].GetParameters();
        if(parameters.Length == 1 && parameters[0].GetType() == typeof(GameObject) && methods[i].ReturnType == typeof(void))
            relevant.Add(methods[i]);
    }
}
```

This code already fails at `GetMethods(..)`which is not returning any methods.
What I do not understand is, that I am able to receive all public methods of any of the relevant classes if they do not implement the interface.

The interface itself does not contain anything, I am only using it to "mark" the relevant classes, as I could not come up with any other solution to do so.

Can anyone tell me why the interface is rendering `GetMethods`useless or point me to the error in my code above?

Comment: Please give a short but *complete* example. Note that you're clearing the `relevant` list completely on every iteration - are you sure you want to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
foreach(System.Type cls in classes)
{    
    methods = cls.GetType().GetMethods(...)
```

`cls` is already a `Type`, so calling `GetType()` on it will return `System.Type` (or a subclass). I suspect you just want:

```
foreach(System.Type cls in classes)
{    
    methods = cls.GetMethods(...)
```

It's also unclear why you're clearing the `relevant` list on each iteration. It means the *only* entries at the end will be the ones from the last class you look at - are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed it! I guess I wasn't thinking when calling GetType() again. 

As to clearing the relevant list every iteration: I am saving the methods' names in a different variable and need different name arrays for each class. I omitted storing the names in the code above as it was not relevant to my question. Once I clear the list, I already got what I wanted from it and can savely do it without any loss of data.

Thanks again for your very quick and helpful response!

Answer (score 3):

As an aside, [Microsoft recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229022%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not using 'marker interfaces' and instead suggests using attributes. You can then [use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.isdefined%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `Memberinfo.IsDefined()` instead of checking for the interface.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I will try changing that as soon as possible!

Answer (score 1):

To find all classes that implements specific interface, you should use rather `IsAssignableFrom` because your code will omit classed that implement your interface indirectly:

```
 Type interfaceType = typeof(IActionMethod);
 Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(interfaceType );
 IEnumerable<System.Type> classes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(x));
```

Then, you probably want to call:

```
 methods = cls.GetMethods(...)
```

because `cls` is your desired type, you are currently searching in its `Type`.

Comment: No class will ever implement the interface indirectly, but I will keep this in mind and will change it later on, if I am unable to mark the classes with attributes like Wai Ha Lee suggested.